# Google App Engine - NDB - Set property value on multiple records

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I'm using NDB and Python on Google App Engine. What is the proper way update a property on multiple entities with the same value? The NDB equivalent of:

`UPDATE notifications SET read = true WHERE user_id = 123`.

The use case is I have these fan-out notifications. And a specific user wants to set all of their notifications as read (potentially 100s). I know that I could use get_async and put_async to fetch each unread notification and set it as read, but I'm worried about the latency that is created by fetching potentially 100s of serializations/deserializations.

Any advice is greatly appericated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call a function for each entity with the [`map()`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queryclass#Query_map) method of Query. For best performance don't forget the `_async`.

But one of the most useful service of GAE is Task Queues, especially in cases like this. If you combine [Query Cursors](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#cursors) and [deferred library](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred), you can easily process any number of entities.

Comment: Task Queues are a good recommendation, I had anticipated that I might need to use them if I truly did need to fetch all the entities in order to update their property.

I wonder about map though. I'm not really transforming (or mapping) any data, IE I don't care about the result. I just need to put data. Still think mapping fits the bill?

Comment: `map()` will work well with a small amount of results, otherwise you want to use the deferred library example. Don't forget to batch your puts together. (call `ndb.put_multi()` vs `model.put()` on each entity)